# Force the Windows input method in the language bar to stay at Microsoft IME with Korean language installed

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, language, ime, korean

I'm sorry if the title doesn't describe my problem properly, but this is what I want to do:

My computer has Windows 7 Ultimate English version, with Korean language installed

I want my input method to stay at MS IME, which is this setting shown below:

[image]

In this mode, I can use the 한/영 button on a Korean hardware keyboard to switch between English and Korean input mode

Sometimes, and I can't point out the reason for it, the input suddenly changes to this mode

[image]

If I were to do this manually, I would have had to click on the keyboard (or globe) icon to bring out the menu, and choose one of them

[image]

The problem is that it is changing to Korean mode automatically, and in this mode I cannot switch between Korean and English input by pressing the 한/영 key (it only inputs in English in this mode)

**How do I force the input method to stay at Microsoft IME?** (this mode [image])

This is what the language bar settings look like at the moment
[image]

Comment: Try moving the Korean keyboard above the English one. It should be default since you have a Korean keyboard.

Comment: @user3169 I've done that before and it didn't work.

Comment: Didn't work or didn't help with the problem? AFAIK, the physical keyboard type needs to be on top.

Comment: I have wondered this myself! Sorry to see there is no answer yet!

Comment: @Jeshii I haven't seen this problem again for quite a while for now, but like I mentioned, it happens randomly. The language bar settings are still same as in the question.